# Add new column showing value change from now to next within id group

Tags: sas

I want to create a new table. I want to go from

```
+-----+------+------+
| id  | time | var1 |
+-----+------+------+
|   1 |    1 |   16 |
|   1 |    2 |   16 |
|   2 |    1 |   10 |
|   2 |    2 |   11 |
|   2 |    3 |   12 |
+-----+------+------+
```

to this

```
+----+------+------+----------+
| id | time | var1 |  change  |
+----+------+------+----------+
|  1 |    1 |   16 | 16 to 16 |
|  2 |    1 |   10 | 10 to 11 |
|  2 |    2 |   11 | 11 to 12 |
+----+------+------+----------+
```

That is to say, I want to add a new column which gives the changes over time per identity. This change should be pasted to the "old" value and not the the "new" value. That is, the change of var1 from time 1 to time 2 should be pasted to time 1 and the last time unit should be removed. I hope someone could help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if there is only one observation in a particular group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier if you just sort by descending time.

```
data have;
  input id time var1;
cards;
1 1 16
1 2 16
2 1 10
2 2 11
2 3 12
;

proc sort data=have;
  by id descending time;
run;

data want ;
  set have ;
  by id ;
  length change $20 ;
  change = catx(' to ',var1,lag(var1));
  if not first.id;
run;

proc sort;
  by id time;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    id    time    var1     change

 1      1      1      16     16 to 16
 2      2      1      10     10 to 11
 3      2      2      11     11 to 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to learn about `LAG` and `FIRST.` flag values that are automatically set when `BY` statements are present in DATA Step.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id;

  prior_var1 = LAG (var1);
  prior_time = LAG (time);

  length change $30;
  if first.id and last.id then do;
    change = 'None, id has one item';
  end;
  else do;
    time = prior_time;
    change = catx(' ', prior_var1, 'to', var1);
  end;

  drop prior:;
run;
```

Another approach is to create a *lead* value of `VAR1` by opening the data set a second time, advanced by one observation, in a 1:1 `MERGE`.  The `first.id` and `last.id` implicit variables are computed directly and not carried into the output data set.

(Fixed after @Tom comment)

```
data have;
  do id = 1 to 5;
    do time = 1 to 3; 
      x+1;
      output;
    end;
  end;
  x+1;
  output;
run;

data want(drop=lead_:);
  merge have have(firstobs=2 keep=id x rename=(id=lead_id x=lead_x));

  first.id = id ne lag(id);
  last.id = id ne lead_id;

  length change $30;
  if first.id and last.id then 
    change = 'n/a';
  else
  if not last.id then 
    change = catx(' ', x, 'to', lead_x);

  if not last.id or first.id;
run;
```

Comment: Note that lead method will not work right for BY group processing. Only the first observation is skipped, not the first observation for each BY group.  On all but the first BY group the LEAD... variables will just be copies of the regular variables.