# Differences in a column by id and skipping rows based on conditions

Tags: sas

I want to calculate the differences in the number column between the endings of a given year and the starts of the next year. The following table

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id |    year    | number |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 | 22Feb2008  |      1 |
|  1 | 8Aug2008   |      2 |
|  1 | 1Jan2009   |      3 |
|  1 | 5Dec2009   |      8 |
|  1 | 2March2010 |      2 |
|  1 | 10Dec2010  |      5 |
|  1 | 5Jan2011   |     12 |
|  1 | 7Nov2011   |      9 |
|  2 | 6Feb2005   |      8 |
|  2 | 8Nov2005   |     12 |
|  2 | 7Apri2006  |      5 |
|  2 | 8Dec2006   |      4 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

should look like

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id |   year    |    change    |
+----+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | 8Aug2008  | from 2 to 3  |
|  1 | 5Dec2009  | from 8 to 2  |
|  1 | 10Dec2010 | from 5 to 12 |
|  2 | 8Nov2005  | from 12 to 5 |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

,
where change is a character. For every id variable, there are either 1 or 2 dates in a given year. I want the change from period t-1 to t to be pasted to the row of period t-1. Since I only care about the change of the second date (end) of a year to the first date (beginning) of the next year, I don't use start 2008 and end 2011, for example.

Comment: What is the format of your `year` variable and what are the actual values?

Comment: They are formatted as dates. So for example 22Aug2019, so not necessarily 31Dec2019. The end of a year is just later than the beginning of a year.

Comment: I am sorry. Apparently this question is badly phrased. What could I do to improve it for the downvoters? Are things unclear? Is this question not suitable/to easy for this site?

Comment: Rephrase it, of course `:)` replace your symbolic `begin 2008` and `end 2008` with actual values, for instance. And explain why you don't want data for `id = 1, year = 2011` and  `id = 2, year = 2016`

Comment: What is the difference calculated ? Are the date values in the year column every disordered within group (id) ? Does a 'year' always contain only two dates ?  This is very similar to your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729413/add-new-column-showing-value-change-from-now-to-next-within-id-group which has an answer demonstrating how to utilize 'lead' data (data from next row).

Comment: I will change. I am sorry for the confusion. It is similar to my previous question, however I don't want to calculate the change of a variable for two dates in the same year. It is, some difference calculations should be skipped. I will add the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same method as your previous question.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57733518/4965549 
Only this time test for a change in the year, `year(date) ne lag(year(date))`, to decide which observation to output.

```
data have;
  input id date number ;
  informat date date.;
  format date date9.;
cards;
1 22Feb2008  1
1  8Aug2008  2
1  1Jan2009  3
1  5Dec2009  8
1  2Mar2010  2
1 10Dec2010  5
1  5Jan2011 12
1  7Nov2011  9
2  6Feb2005  8
2  8Nov2005 12
2  7Apr2006  5
2  8Dec2006  4
;

proc sort data=have out=want ;
  by id descending date ;
run;

data want ;
  set want;
  by id ;
  change=catx(' to ',number,lag(number));
  if year(date) ne lag(year(date)) and not first.id then output;
run;

proc sort; by id date; run;
proc print; run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    id         date    number    change

 1      1    08AUG2008       2      2 to 3
 2      1    05DEC2009       8      8 to 2
 3      1    10DEC2010       5      5 to 12
 4      2    08NOV2005      12      12 to 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your year is actually a date, we calculate the year;

```
data HAVE_VW / view=HAVE_VW; /* you donot have to make this a view, but it saves time and space */
    set HAVE;
    by id year; /* This is not needed, but if your input data is not sorted as assumed, this will at least give an error */

    year_nr = year(year);
run;



data WANT;
    set HAVE_VW;
    by id year_nr;


    /* remember the number at the beginning of the year */
    if first.year_nr then begin_number = number;
    retain begin_number; /* a variable that is not retained is initialized for each observation (aga row) */

    if last.year_nr then do;
        change = compbl('from '||put(begin_number, 8.)||' to '||put(number, 8.)); /* calculate the change */

        output; /* If you add an output statement all observations for which you do not execute an output are deleted */
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

**HAVE:**

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id | year       | number |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | start 2008 | 1      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | end 2008   | 2      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | start 2009 | 3      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | end 2009   | 8      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | start 2010 | 2      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | end 2010   | 5      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | start 2011 | 12     |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | end 2011   | 9      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 2  | start 2005 | 8      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 2  | end 2005   | 12     |
+----+------------+--------+
| 2  | start 2006 | 5      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 2  | end 2006   | 4      |
+----+------------+--------+
```

**SOLUTION:**(if data correctly sorted before)

```
data want(drop=number start);
   set have;
   by id;
   length change $100;
   retain start;
   if first.id then start=.;
   if index(strip(year),'end') then start = number;
   else if index(strip(year),'start') and start ne . then do;
      change = "from "|| strip(start) || " to " || strip(number);
      output;
   end;
run;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
+----+------------+--------------+
| id | year       | change       |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 1  | start 2009 | from 2 to 3  |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 1  | start 2010 | from 8 to 2  |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 1  | start 2011 | from 5 to 12 |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 2  | start 2006 | from 12 to 5 |
+----+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Note that some adaptations will have to be made if actual numbers are larger. It is assumed that the data set is ordered by date within each subject. Also note that this gives the change from the end of one year to the start of the next year in the data set, wether or not these are succesive.

```
data input;
    input id $ 1-1 @3 date date9.  number;
    format date ddmmyy10.;
    numyear=year(date);
datalines;
1 01JAN2008 1
1 31DEC2008 2
1 02FEB2009 3
1 31DEC2009 8
1 01JAN2010 2
1 02JAN2010 5
1 01JAN2011 12
1 31DEC2011 9
2 01JAN2005 8
2 31DEC2005 12
2 01JAN2006 5
2 31DEC2006 4
;

data output;
    set input;
        by id numyear;
    retain year change0 ;
    /*  Reaching the end of a year, store some values that are retained to the next lines*/
    if last.numyear then do;
        year=cat("end ",put(numyear, 4.0));
        change0=cat("from ", strip(put(number,3.)));
    end;
    /*  Starting a new year, combine retained values with new ones, and output.*/
    if first.numyear and not first.id then do;
        change=cat(strip(change0), " to ", strip(put(number,3.)));
        /*  Comment out the following lines will make it easier to follow the logic of the program*/
        keep id year change;
        output;
    end;
run;
```